# Device to swap display input?

Tags: display, external-display, hardware-rec, laptop-display

I'm looking for a device that will let me patch in my laptop when needed to my desktop setup. I have two monitors using hdmi and dvi-I from my gfx card.

I want to be able to hookup my laptop when I need to work on work related stuff and be able to use my two monitors without disconnection them from my desktop.

I'm looking for some sort of middleman device? Does such a device/cable exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood correctly, are you just looking for a KVM hardware wise. 
The spendy solution probably overkill: [Dual Monitor DVI KVM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002VY8T2Y)

You could also just get one cheap DVI switch box for each monitor which would be cheaper and only one extra button press, you might need to physically move a USB cable or two.
[HDMI switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01L8LLP2G)

Comment: See my edits above, sorry!